# X axis is not showing on graph in an R Box Plot

Tags: r, plot

I cannot seem to get my x and y labels to fit on my graph.

My original coding was

```
    ana1$B<-factor(ana1$Burn,c("C","N","L","S"))
    with(ana1,boxplot(Time~ana1$B, ylab  = "Infiltration Rate (mm/h) " , xlab = "Burn Treatment", las = 2, par(mar = c(10, 4, 4, 1)+0.1), names = c( "Control" , "Not burned since 1954" , "Long rotation burn" , "Short rotation burn" ) ) )
```

and this produced this boxplot:

[image: Axis labels are overlapped]

I was informed to edit the code to use title to manually draw and axis title and adjust its position through the line parameter.

I need to edit both the x and the y axis, however first off I just tried to rewrite the code to complete the x axis

The new code I produced is below

```
   ana1$B<-factor(ana1$Burn,c("C","N","L","S"))
   with(ana1,boxplot(Time~ana1$B, par(mar = c(12, 6, 4, 1)+0.1), ylab  = "Infiltration Rate (m/h)" , xlab = "", las = 2, title(xlab = "Burn Treatment", line = 10), names = c( "Control" , "Not burned since 1954" , "Long rotation burn" , "Short rotation burn" ) ) )
```

As you may see, I have attempted to increase the parameter as instructed and have altered the code to include the title xlab, however I am clearly inputting this wrong as when I run the code, the x axis label is not on the graph at all.

[image: new code and new boxplot]

I am a complete beginner to R. Though it may seem simple I just want to move my x axis labels as soon as possible and I cannot!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example by providing your dataset or a subset e.g. paste the output of `dput(ana1)` in your question.

Comment: Check by decreasing `line=10` to a smaller value, you might have the title go off the viewable page